# Linux search for word and show entire line

Tags: linux, grep

I have a very large log file (6 gig).

I want to search for '`Nov 12 2012`' and print off each line.

I'm a linux novice and have no idea how this is done.  Mostly likely will need a more option to view X number of lines and move forward thru the search.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
grep --after-context=5 --before-context=10 'Nov 12 2012' yourfile.log
```

That'll show each line that contains your date text, as well as 10 lines of text BEFORE the line that matched, and 5 lines AFTER the line that matched.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I needed this too Marc B.  Extremely helpful.

Comment: I used `grep --after-context=5 --before-context=10 'Nov 12 2012' yourfile.log | tail -n 80` to only show the last 5 occurrences including the 10 lines before and 5 after. 5*(1+10+5)=80

Answer (score 15):

You can use `grep` to show matching lines and `less` as a pager:

```
grep 'Nov 12 2012' /path/to/logfile | less
```

Type 'space' at the end of each page to advance to the next screen of results.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `grep` as follows:

```
grep 'Nov 12 2012' file_to_search.log > search_results.log
```

Some explanations:

- `grep` is the name of the command / tool used for searching patterns
- `'Nov 12 2012'`: immediately after `grep` and separated by at least 1 space, you specify the pattern you want to search for
- `file_to_search.log`: as the last argument to `grep` here, you specify the file(s) you want to search for
- `> search_results.log`: The `>` means output [redirection](http://www.linuxsa.org.au/tips/io-redirection.html). Here it means "write the output from this command to a file called `search_results.log`. If the file exists already, overwrite it completely.

After getting the output, you can view the results with a text editor of your choice, or with `less`, so use any of the following:

```
less search_results.log
gedit search_results.log
emacs search_results.log
vim search_results.log
```

Answer (score 4):

Open the file in a script format and then search with the keyword which you want to find as follows.

```
$vi <logfilename>
     &
:/search
```

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -A 5 -B 10 'Nov 12 2012' <yourfile.log>
```

`-A <n>` to view `n` lines after and `-B <n>` for `n` lines before.
Or, for both together `-C <n>` i.e display `n` lines before and after the searched text.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good way for locating errors at big log files : grep --after-context=5 --before-context=10 'Error' yourfile.log  or grep --after-context=5 --before-context=10 'Exception' yourfile.log

Comment: Specify that this is using `grep`